# How to change clustered column chart group fill color

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts, apexcharts

I want to change every column in clustered column chart that be all group same color. I want the same result in the image attached.

Apex chart or am chart or any other library.

[image]

i can do this only all group has same color.

[image]

Comment: Is this what you want? [Bar Chart Example](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/basic/)

Comment: Yes ,but i want every each group of bar has same color like first image .